# Mongoimport fails due to duplicated ids of documents from another server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, duplicates, mongoimport

I have 2 servers (A and B) that are running a node.js API for logging events in a MongoDB database (each server has a different -independent- MongoDB instance)
Some day I just wanted to turn down server B and migrate its log data to server A by executing mongomport in server B and moving the resulting file to server A (using mongoimport)

The first time I couldn't complete the mongoimport because the process detected duplicated _ids (the node.js processes use mongoose with default unique index _id)

Taking into account logs data does not require a unique id at all (but it is mandatory in MongoDB collections to have a unique _id) the mongoimport should have worked but the id didn't.

In theory, MongoDB ObjectId is guaranteed to be unique in the same collections but in this case, there is the same application running and saving data in 2 independent servers.
The only solution for this was to remove the _id fields from all records in the exported JSON from server B in order to import them in server A.

**I suppose there should be a better way for doing this because I was very surprised that there were ObjectIds duplicated so easily in 2 different databases.**

Log data consists of documents like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("568c5ed728f0e80214860784"),
    "event" : "event1",
    "clientCode" : "CLIENTCODE01",
    "created" : ISODate("2016-01-06T00:24:20.000Z"),
    "updated" : ISODate("2016-01-06T00:27:00.000Z")
}
```

**Important: server A had only CLIENTCODE01 logs while server B had only CLIENTCODE02 logs so the migration to server A goal was to join the 2 clients' log data into one single server.**

Any ideas about how to deal with this?